# cakephp session error in cli

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am new to CakePHP framework (more of the Yii guy), so my question might look stupid to someone, however I am stuck with this problem all day. I am trying to create console command to execute in shell, however there is something wrong with Session initialization (?) I constantly get error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cookie in E:\htdocs\project\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php on line 485
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: timeout in E:\htdocs\project\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php on line 491
PHP Warning:  ini_set(): session.name cannot be a numeric or empty '' in E:\htdocs\project\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php on line 500
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CakeSessionException' with message 'Unable to configure the session, setting session.name failed.' in E:\htdocs\project\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php:501
```

Why cakephp doesn't load core.php config values? In my config I set:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));

Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'PROJECT');
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '28800');
```

CakePHP version 2.4.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if anyone will come to this problem, there is thing to notice. In windows you can't run `cake` command... Well you can, but notice line in `cake.bat` file:

```
:: In order for this script to work as intended, the cake\console\ folder must be in your PATH
```

or run `php cake.php`...